# Using Powershell on W2K3 to get group policy

Tags: powershell, scripting, group-policy, windows-2003-webserver

Trying to create a script to get the group policy. Originally I thought this was going to be simple, after discovering several group policy cmdlets, however I've noticed that all the group policy cmdlets are for W2K8 and up.

I've been searching around, and so far haven't found anything on if it's possible to get group policy using Powershell for a W2K3 server, so was wandering if anyone here might have any suggestions on where to start.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly I believe you are stuck with gpresult in W2k3, as the cmdlets you want are part of the RSAT's Group Policy Management Tools.

I saw some third party items out there, but they appear to just be wrappers on the RSAT, so again they would most likely not work in Server 2003.